# Why does "$pull" does'nt work with findbyidandupdate request?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

[image: This is the user document , todos is an array of id of todo document]

[image: this is the todos document]
**NB : I have this warning : DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: `findOneAndUpdate()` and `findOneAndDelete()` without the `useFindAndModify` option set to false are deprecated.** 
I don't know what does it mean this warning

```
router.put('/deleteTodoFromUser/:id/:idTodo', passport.authenticate('bearer'), (req, res) => {

  User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $pull: { todos: req.params.idTodo } }, (err, usr) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
    res.send(usr);
  });
})
```

Comment: can you please post some sample data?

Comment: It is just an array of string in a document (todos)

Comment: Do you want to remove the reference todo id in user or do you want to delete both the reference in user and the todo in todos collection?

Comment: Just I want to delete the reference in user

Comment: Then @JBone answer must work as expected, it just returns the old document, but actually deletes the referenced todo. You can get the updated document by adding a third option like this `{new: true}`. This must be after pull options like this `{ $pull: { todos: { $eq: req.params.idTodo } } }, {new: true}`

Comment: @SuleymanSah I tried it , it returns the old one without deleting referenced todo id

Comment: @HassenBouzlima I will soon post an answer of mine, with step by step.

Comment: @SuleymanSah so I'm going to give you further information to get a clear view. I have two schemas user and todo the user has a lot of attributes among them an array of ID(todos) of the referenced todo schema . I tried user.update , user.findbyidandudate , user.findoneandUpdate and they did not work , I'm almsot sure that the problem is in $pull cause the request always return the old document without deleting the referenced todo Id .

Comment: @HassenBouzlima can you check my answer? I also put User and Todo schemas, maybe you have problem there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JBones's answer must work as expected.

But to solve your problem, here I explain step by step.

User schema:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  todos: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Todo"
    }
  ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Todo schema:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  completed: Boolean
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Todo", todoSchema);
```

route:

```js
router.put("/deleteTodoFromUser/:id/:idTodo", (req, res) => {
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    { $pull: { todos: { $in: [req.params.idTodo] } } },
    { new: true },
    (err, usr) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
      }
      if (usr) {
        res.send(usr);
      } else {
        res.status(400).send("Bad request - User not found");
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Test:

Let's say you have these 3 todo documents in your todos collection.

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5dfa6776e1783d0c10a8d827"),
        "name" : "Todo 3",
        "completed" : true,
        "__v" : NumberInt(0)
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5dfa676fe1783d0c10a8d826"),
        "name" : "Todo 2",
        "completed" : false,
        "__v" : NumberInt(0)
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5dfa6768e1783d0c10a8d825"),
        "name" : "Todo 1",
        "completed" : false,
        "__v" : NumberInt(0)
    }
]
```

And  a user document like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dfa846379db991c3c4341e4"),
    "todos" : [
        ObjectId("5dfa6768e1783d0c10a8d825"),
        ObjectId("5dfa676fe1783d0c10a8d826"),
        ObjectId("5dfa6776e1783d0c10a8d827")
    ],
    "name" : "User 1",
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

When we try to delete the todo id 5dfa676fe1783d0c10a8d826, for user id 5dfa846379db991c3c4341e4, 
the url must be something like this `http://...../deleteTodoFromUser/5dfa846379db991c3c4341e4/5dfa676fe1783d0c10a8d826`

the result will be like this: (5dfa676fe1783d0c10a8d826 is removed)

```
{
    "todos": [
        "5dfa6768e1783d0c10a8d825",
        "5dfa6776e1783d0c10a8d827"
    ],
    "_id": "5dfa846379db991c3c4341e4",
    "name": "User 1",
    "__v": 0
}
```

And indeed if you check the users collection, you will see 2 todos in your user document.

Comment: The same , maybe the problem is in my mongoose version . cause the same happen with this request : 
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $set: { $addToSet: { todos: req.params.idTodo } } }, (err, usr) => {

Comment: @HassenBouzlima with these schemas and code, it should work. Can you add a few documents for users and todos to your question? I think the problem is how you save data.

Comment: the problem happened just for updating when I want to add a referenced Id of todo and when I want to delete it

Comment: @HassenBouzlima can you show sample documents by editing your question? Also it may help if you show how you save your documents.

Comment: check it now and I added a warning happening to me

Comment: @HassenBouzlima that warning can be resolved by modifying mongoose connect options, that is not the reason for problem. Are you sure you are sending the correct params in the url? What url do you use?

Comment: Thank you sulemanSah , I resolved the problem , your answers was very helpful for me

Comment: @HassenBouzlima you are welcome, so the problem was how you saved the document? I think you can consider to accept may answer:)

Answer (score 2):

I think the syntax needs to be like this:

```js
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    { $pull: { todos: { $in: [req.params.idTodo] } } },
    { new: true },
    (err, usr) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      }
      res.send(usr);
    }
  );
```

Look at [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) link at official docs.

Comment: is this method `findByIdAndUpdate` exists in the mongo version that you are using? seems like it does not in the latest version according to the documentation

Comment: it exists , but in my case return just the same object without update .

Comment: may be you want to consider `findOneAndUpdate`

Comment: console.log(`the value is ${req.params.idTodo}`)  ..see what it prints

Comment: the backticks does not show in the above console log body for some reason. just print that value before you do the update method

Comment: the same for findOneAndUpdate

Comment: console.log(the value is ${req.params.idTodo})  returns the right value

Comment: well, replace that `right value` with `req.params.idTodo` and see I guess. If this does not work then there is something else going on. According to the documentation, the syntax seems to be correct. Make sure the data type that is coming in matched with the data type that array has.

Comment: stills does'nt work , the problem is I can't know the error because findbyIdAndUpdate return the old value if there is not an update so it is difficult to know the problem . and todos is an array of objectId in a document , even when i converted req.params.idTodo to objectId , it doesn't work also

Comment: ok if this is the case, then do the query `$pull` on one of the MongoBD editors like `NoSQLBooster` or `RoboMongo` first. make sure the query syntax works and then plug that query into the program. this way, at least you are making sure the query is working with the values you have. If the query itself is not working, fixing that would be a lot easier on one of those said editors. I wish I could do more, but I don't have any of those editors at my work and `mongoPlayground` does not support the method you are using.  keep it posted here your findings. Someone  might benefit from it

Comment: @JBone your answer actually works, but without `{new:true}` option, it returns the old document, so I guess it confuses Hassen, so I updated your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I find the problem :

- First I was adding Id to the array in mongodb manually so I think it occurs a problem
- My add to set request was not working properly : User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,  { **$set**{$addToSet: { todos: req.params.idTodo } }} --> $set is wrong here just I implement this request without $set and it worked .

> so after that I was able to add Id to todo array not manually but by a mongoose request . 
>   *as I said also I had a warning : * 
>    **DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: findOneAndUpdate() and findOneAndDelete() without the useFindAndModify option set to false are deprecated**

for that I added :
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Db_Todo',{**useUnifiedTopology:true,useNewUrlParser:true,useFindAndModify:false}**);